# How can I extract data from Jsoup parser library?

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

Hello guys I'm trying on extract data from a url.
This is my simple code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class GetProxyServer {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String url = "http://proxy.dongsuya.net/proxy_speed.php";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element proxyTable = doc.getElementById("proxy_table");
    Elements proxies_tds = proxyTable.select("td:contains(:)"); 
    System.out.println(proxies_tds);
    }
}
```

now I can see from console like :

```
<td class="col_B">110.4.12.170:81</td>
<td class="col_B">202.171.253.83:84</td>
<td class="col_A">y094228.ppp.asahi-net.or.jp:80</td>...
```

the problem is, I can't extract inside data. I want to bring "110.4.12.170:81" only.
I try this :

```
for (Element proxies_td : proxies_tds){
        String onlyData = proxies_tds.text();
    }
```

But I can't display to console the variable "onlyData".
How can I do that? and also, How can I save the datas one by one to String?

Comment: Take a hard look at the statement inside the for loop: `String onlyData = proxies_tds.text();`  Try changing `proxies_tds` to `proxies_td`; after all, you want to apply `text()` to each individual cell.

Comment: @MCL Thanks. I solved this problem. Thank you. Hava a good christmas!

Comment: To you, too. Would you please post it as an answer then?

Comment: @MCL I'm newbie of stackoverflow. How can I do that?

Comment: Scroll down ans type an answer in the textfield under **Your Answer**. After a certain amount of time, you will be able to accept it by clicking the checkmark to its side.

Answer (score 0):

Take a hard look at the statement inside the for loop: `String onlyData = proxies_tds.text();` Try changing `proxies_tds` to `proxies_td;` after all, you want to apply text() to each individual cell. –Credits to  MCL